# Convergence of $z_n = \sqrt[n]{ni}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to study the convergence of

$$z_n = \sqrt[n]{ni}$$

but I don't even know where to start since the nth root of a complex number can have up to n values... How do I even begin analyzing such thing?

Comment: In many cases to choose which value of $n$-th root has no effect on the convergence. In other cases you may need to get more information around the place where the problem is formulated.

Comment: Note that $$e^{i(\pi/2+2k\pi)/n}$$  for $k=0,1,\cdots n-1$.  So, as $n$ increases, the number of roots increases also.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$i=e^{i\pi/2},$$
and thus $$\sqrt[n]{i}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2n}}.$$

Comment: That's one of them, the principal branch.  It's not clear whether the OP wants to use the principal branch or all branches.  The "up to $n$ values" would seem to indicate the latter.

Comment: Nice, so it converges to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right. At each stage, there will be $n$ different $n$-th roots, all equally spaced about a circle of radius $\sqrt[n]n$ centered at the origin. You may choose the one of these that’s closest to $\sqrt[n]n$, as in @Surb’s answer, giving a limit of $1$, but as an algebraist, I see no justification for such a choice. The total “limit”, of these increasingly many roots, would be the whole unit circle.

In my opinion, this was an ill-conceived question, and its author should be roundly excoriated.